# Dropbox XAMPP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, dropbox

I have relocated my htdocs folder to be within my dropbox folder and would like to do a similar thing with my MySQL databases. I don't know if this is even possible or advisable so would love to hear anyones advice and thoughts.

Should I be doing this and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would discourage it deeply :)

But... you can change you're path to whatever you want...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

You can simply add the flag each time you start mysqld, or you could add it to the [mysqld] section of your user-wide/machine-wide mysql config file.

You will need to initialize the tables first, using the mysql_install_db script ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html )

Comment: Why would you discourage this. Could you please explain so I could understand. I'd like to learn why

Comment: It's just very very wrong :) ... if it's for messing about and experimenting... I'd say go for it - hesitantly... but if it's for anything more than that... proper just use some sever hosting that allows connecting to DB from outside their network (i.e. not from you're web server), or if you need it on more than one location using proper replication.

Comment: What is "proper replication"? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: setting up 2 or more sql servers to update each other. As i said if it's purley for you're own use and development setting it to use dropbox should be ok... I have done it too... just make sure there is only one 'instance' of mysql accesing it at any one time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have local server installed on my dropbox works perfectly I only use it for testing purposes so no production sites run from it but its a great way to run local sites/test that sync to all your computers.

Comment: This is sort of the same use I would be using it for. I wan't to be able to use this as a development tool. I won't be hosting production sites from here, but I will be creating them. Did you have to do anything special for running an XAMPP server from within Dropbox?

Comment: I found XAMPP did run without issue but the paths needs adjusting on every computer I was on due to the different drive names so I used another one that worked without any special setup called usb web server http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/